maven site possibly giving incorrect Java version in dependencies report
For a number of maven dependencies, I'm trying to figure out what is the latest version of that dependency that is compatible with a Java 8 application.
So this is the only dependency in my pom.xml (other than maven-site-plugin and maven-project-info-reports-plugin):
#         <dependency>
#             <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
#             <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
#             <version>2.0</version>
#         </dependency>

I ran mvn site to generate the dependencies report, and the report says that snakeyaml-2.0.jar uses Java 9. However, if look at the pom.xml file for maven.org.yaml.snakeyaml, it says:
#         <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
#         <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>

And I've written a small snippet of code using snakeyaml, compiled and run it with Java 8, and it works just fine. So it would appear that the dependency is, in fact, compatible with Java 8, even though the maven-generated report says it uses Java 9. Does anyone know what's going on here? Is there a better way to determine the minimum Java version required to use a specific dependency in my project?

Which report have you generated ? How? Also I assume that snakeyaml contains a module-info.class which is the indicator for JDK9+

@khmarbaise It's the dependencies report (dependencies.html) generated by maven-project-info-reports-plugin. I just included maven-project-info-reports-plugin and maven-site-plugin in my pom.xml, and then ran "mvn site" from the menu in IntelliJ. And yes, snakeyaml does contain a module-info.class.
